# Sorting out erroneous events in MATLAB using a for loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I have some problems with a line of script in MATLAB that is supposed to sort out erroneously detected events. So basically, I have these 2 variables `spikemax` and `spikethresh`, which contain indices into my data trace. `spikemax` contains correct indices to timepoints in my data trace, but `spikethresh` has still too many values and I need to sort some of them out.
The rule is supposed to be, that every value of `spikethresh` is always followed by a `spikemax` before the next `spikethresh`. I have added an image that shows with red and green dots where my two variables eventually indicate in the data trace.

My idea is to run a for loop with a condition that deletes values from `spikethresh` to update the variable. In the code I added some example values that show simply what is not working.
The output here is `[15029;15055;15066;15339]`, but I am trying to get

```
spikethresh = [15029;15066;15339]
```

How can I fix my code so it produces the desired output?

Here's my code:

```
% Example variables:
spikethresh = [15029; 15038;15055; 15060; 15066; 15339];
spikemax= [15034; 15072; 15344];

spikethresh_corr = spikethresh ;

for i = 1:length(spikemax)-1
    if (spikethresh(i+1)-spikethresh(i)) < (spikemax(i)-spikethresh(i))
        spikethresh_corr(i) = [] ; 
    end
    spikethresh = spikethresh_corr ;
end 


% Results in spikethresh = [15029;15055;15066],
% but I am trying to get [15029;15066;15339]
```

Comment: Does filloutliers() help? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filloutliers.html 
I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but this is a ready to use detector that I think can be used for your purposes with a few tweaks here and there.

Comment: @GuarneerFPS: I am not sure if the filloutliers function works for my purpose as I don't apply a general rule but rather a condition from one variable to the other, but I'll have a look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

1. `(spikethresh(i+1)-spikethresh(i)) < (spikemax(i)-spikethresh(i))` doesn't really test your condition. What you want to test is `spikethresh(i+1) < spikemax(i)`. That is, if the next value in `spikethresh` is smaller than the current one in `spikemax`, we don't need the current value in `spikethresh`.
2. You do your test exactly 2 times (`length(spikemax)-1` is 2). But you might have more elements to remove. For each `i`, you have to repeatedly apply your test until it no longer is satisfied (there are no more values to remove that come before the current `spikemax(i)`).

This is what your code would look like:

```matlab
spikethresh = [15029; 15038; 15055; 15060; 15066; 15339];
spikemax = [15034; 15072; 15344];

for i = 1:length(spikemax)-1
   while spikethresh(i+1) < spikemax(i)
      spikethresh(i) = [];
   end
end
```

This results in `spikethresh = [15029; 15066; 15339]`.

Comment: Thank you! That works well and solved the logical error I made in the first place. In the end, I noticed that the part that got me the variable ```spikethresh``` in the first place had some other problems, so I rewrote it completely. Thanks for your help!